# Correct layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing simple Android application. Here is the mockup of the layout I want to create (just to give you an idea). [image]

On both sides there will be 4 pictures with words.
What would be the best way to do that? Here is what I have so far. Is that OK or is there any better way to do that?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#B36E106F"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false"
tools:context=".AddRoute" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/add_left_column"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#0098FF" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/abc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="From" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/abc" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/add_right_column"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#0098FF" >

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### you will love this

[image: preview]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal">



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />
        <TextView
            android:text="hello"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />
        <TextView
            android:text="hello"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />
        <TextView
            android:text="hello"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />
        <TextView
            android:text="hello"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/abc_spinner_ab_focused_holo_dark">
    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

I am using the layout_weight trick to make the left linearLayout and right linearlayout to be the same width.

what you need to do is modify the style, backgournd, margin and padding.

reading the google android docs won`t get you pregnant,so do more reading.

[google design guide for linearLayout and layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Example)

Answer (score 1):

i would do it like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#B36E106F"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".AddRoute" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_left_column"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#0098FF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!--  Images here -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_right_column"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#0098FF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <!--  Images here -->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

LinearLayout is a lot faster than RelativeLayout, at least if you use relative layouts features like alignToRightOf and similar methods.

But as your not using any features, why using it at all?

besides that you should change your weight to 0.5 as you want them to split the space equally. 100% => 1 except if you set a different weightSum

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of the pictures on the both sides are determined. You can use a Horizontal LinearLayout with two Vertical LinearLayout inside it. And use the layout_weight attribute to let them split the parent layout equally. Like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Put your image and textView in the 8 horizontalLinearLayout.

Then if the number of images is determined during the runtime, you can try [staggereGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView).